# jax-ws: what exactly does the "keep" flag in the "wsgen" tool do?

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsgen

What exactly does the `keep` flag in the `wsgen` tool do? I am using the default command-line implementation that ships with Oracle Java 7 (at: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/wsgen`).

The documentation says: "Keep generated files" however I 've tried both:

```
wsgen -cp dist/foo.jar -r ../client/ -s ../client/src-auto/ -keep foo.Hello
```

and

```
wsgen -cp dist/foo.jar -r ../client/ -s ../client/src-auto/       foo.Hello
```

and the generated files are always overwritten (both the Java client stub files and the wsdl files). The same behavior is shown by the [`wsgen` Ant task](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.1/docs/wsgenant.html) - the `keep` attribute doesn't seem to 
produce any effects whether `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wsgen` generates your web service artifacts, compiles them and keeps only the `.class` files. By using the `-keep` option you are telling `wsgen` to also keep the generated `.java` files.

`-s` instructs `wsgen` to keep the `.java` files and place them at the specified location at which point I think the `-keep` option is ignored since you used the `-s` option (you did so in both your examples).

Try playing with a simple command with just `-keep` and see when it keeps `.java` files and when it does not.

Comment: So it's a case of bad options design as that's really only one option (keep the damned sources or not!)

Comment: @Bodgan, yes I confirm what you think. `-keep` is ignored with `-s` and only becomes relevant if the `-d` flag is used instead.